# yarn job is submitted but no progress and not running

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

i have a mapreduce job which i submitted with mapreduce.execution.framework=yarn  with the following command .

`yarn jar  dataquality.jar ey_id.dataquality /user/prasanna/ipfile /user/prasanna/opfile`

the job is submitted with a job_id and shows that it is running , but it stays still..

```
[root@cch1utbig3 prasanna]# yarn jar  dataquality.jar ey_id.dataquality /user/prasanna/ipfile /user/prasanna/opfile
15/01/29 12:45:16 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/172.25.121.245:8050
15/01/29 12:45:17 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/01/29 12:45:18 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/01/29 12:45:18 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/01/29 12:45:19 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1422468943255_0006
15/01/29 12:45:19 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1422468943255_0006
15/01/29 12:45:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1422468943255_0006/
15/01/29 12:45:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1422468943255_0006
```

.. am i missing anything here ?